# Is there a way to restart quickly to last checkpoint (without killing yourself)?

Tags: diablo-iii

For some heavily repeating achievements, I would need to quickly go back to last checkpoint.

With no quickload function, how to get back to last checkpoint without killing yourself (and getting that nasty 10% durability loss)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to return to the most recent checkpoint by leaving the game (as opposed to exiting Diablo 3, though that also works) and re-entering.

Comment: Keep in mind that this respawns all monsters.

Comment: True, it depends on what achievements he's looking to do.  I was assuming chest opening/destruction/etc, and this method will reset those appropriately.  Others may not merit the respawn (unsure of what they might be though).

Answer (score 2):

Leaving a game and re-entering is the fastest way to return to a checkpoint, but do note that if you're in a dangerous area (ie, not in town) you'll want to town portal first - this is faster than waiting out the "Leaving Game..." timer.

In addition to all of the monsters (and so forth) respawning, this also rerolls all the random maps, and may give you different "events" in the level you were exploring.

The town portal takes about 4 seconds, and then you can leave immediately, while the timer takes 10 seconds.  If your last checkpoint was within a dungeon, you'll resume the game from there - even if you exit to town first.

Do note that if you need to go back further than the last checkpoint (ie, if you're trying to get a boss-related achievement), you'll have to change your current quest on the character selection menu.  There's not an entry in the current quest menu for every checkpoint, so plan to lose a bit of time getting back to wherever you were before.

Comment: But won't your portal dissapear if you leave and come back?

Comment: @Fredy31, yes, the portal will disappear.  However, you'll start from within the dungeon, if that's where you last hit a checkpoint.

Comment: @Fredy31 You'll be respawned at your last checkpoint, not in town, so the town portal is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you sure that's true?  I just ended up in town, even though I quit literally at a checkpoint... and I now need to clear a level to get back to the checkpoint from a waypoint.